# get contents after string is found in text file (get version from file)

Tags: powershell

I am wanting to get the version string located in another powershell file. Specifically I am trying to get the second part of a string file:

```
$releaseVersion = "1.0.1.254"
```

I am able to find the string itself by loading the return of `Get-Content` into a variable and using `.Contains()`, but I cant seem to get the remaining characters in that line.

```bsh
  # === base === #
  $myVersion = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Start-NewDeviceSetup.ps1';
  $myVersion.Contains("$ReleaseVersion"); # returns true
  Select-String -InputObject $myVersion -Pattern '$releaseVersion' 
  # returns nothing

  # === other testing === #
  $a = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\Start-NewDeviceSetup.ps1" | Select-String -Pattern '$releaseVersion'
  $a.Matches # also returns nothing
  $a.gettype(); # You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

  # === other information === #
  $myVersion.GetType(); # System.Array
  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion # 5.1.17763.503
```

Looking to just get a return of what the version of the file is (string). 
I have it stored in a variable as I also want it to be displayed whenever the script is running so I can make it easier to identify if people need to be updated.

Comment: Remove the '-quotes around `$releaseVersion`, and make sure you escape the `.`'s: `Select-String -Pattern ([regex]::Escape($releaseVersion))`

Comment: To just get the version number from the other script file: `(Select-String '\$releaseVersion = "([0-9.]+)"' .\Start-NewDeviceSetup.ps1).Matches.Groups[1].Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Content` stores each line into an index within an array. Therefore, you can select the location of `$ReleaseVersion` by finding whatever line it is on and then place the index on `$myVersion[]`.

```
  $myVersion = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Start-NewDeviceSetup.ps1';
  #You dont need this bool. $myVersion.Contains("$ReleaseVersion"); # returns true
  $myVersion = $myVersion[indexlocation of the value]
  $string = $myVersion -replace ""anything you may need to delete out", """
```

`.Contains` is a boolean method, it only conditions whether the statement is true or false, so this is not needed. It's not giving you the value because it's not storing the actual value you are looking for.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Does have one problem though. If the contents above that ever get edited then it will break. I can work around that though (add it into a comment or something).

Comment: The best way to ensure it wouldn't break is to validate the index with an `if statement`. I'm not sure what the entirety of the data looks like, but based on what you informed that would be your best bet. Or, like you said, add it into a comment.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to read a value from a Powershell file, it is better to use dot-sourcing then reading content as text. Once you dot-source a powershell file in your current script, you will have access to all the variables, arrays, hashtables, etc.

```
. "C:\Temp\Start-NewDeviceSetup.ps1"
```